# Android é showing as black diamond in email intent

Tags: android, email, android-intent, special-characters

I'm building a simple app in Android studio and using the ACTION_SEND intent to send a pre-populated email. For some reason gmail is not showing the "é" correctly in the subject of the email (black diamond with a question mark instead). Below is the code I'm using:

```
        public static final String s="String with é";
        byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String emailSubject="";
        try{
            emailSubject = new String(b, "UTF-8");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("application/image");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject + " - blabla");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textIntent);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(emailIntent, GMAILSENT);
```

Thank you,

Comment: In which mobile you are testing? I used your exact code, it's working fine on my OnePlus 6T OS 10. Instead of Java I am just using Kotlin.

Comment: It's a LG-M327, I can type the "é" in the subject of the email and it shows correctly

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by adding the following line in gradle:
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'